# Tag Synonym request: [filters] -> [filter]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There's only a few questions under [filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters), but it's pretty clearly a synonym for [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter). Can it please be made such?

Comment: Do you not have enough rep/privilege to suggest a tag synonym for this tag?

Comment: I do not. (I tried.) Need a score of 5 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done; the synonym is now active